# Is there an easy way to tell where your rep has come from?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Before anyone blurts out with a "check the rep tab on your profile", let me explain myself properly.

There is (generally) 3 types of rep income:

- Upvotes/Downvotes
- Accepted answers
- Bounties

These three can affect your rep both positively and negatively. So is there an easy way to determine what has affected your rep, and how? For example, if I wanted to find out how much bounties have affected my rep, or how much upvotes/downvotes have?

To refine my question, I'm asking is there a simple, easy function that can find all the rep income sources of one type, without having to trawl through your rep history?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? What would you do with this information?

Comment: @murgatroid99 in all honesty it's simply a "counting your eggs" situation for me I feel. As for why it exists, that's a different question :)

Comment: I know SE is working on a new design for the profile page - it's possible it shows this level of breakdown

Comment: You can find how many times you got upvoted by adding up all of your tag scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with bounties by checking the "bounties" tab in your profile. The "offered" sub-tab shows the rep you have lost to offering bounties, and the "earned" sub-tab shows the rep you have gained from earning bounties.

You can also see this for answers you have accepted by checking the "accepts" sub-tab of the "activity" tab, and you can probably figure it out for answers you have downvoted by checking the "downvotes" sub-tab of the "votes" tab and checking which links point to answers.

You didn't mention this, but you can also figure out what rep you have gained from suggested edits by looking at the "suggestions" sub-tab of the "activity" tab.

As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to find rep changes **only** from votes and acceptances on your own answers.